# An error occurred during installation: No such plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I installed Jenkins 2.19.3 on my Rhel 8 server and I able to see the jenkins GUI successfully. The problem is the Plugins aren't installed. I referred some forum and edit the jenkins file which is located in init.d folder.

JAVA_CMD="$JENKINS_JAVA_CMD $JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS -DJENKINS_HOME=$JENKINS_HOME -jar $JENKINS_WAR"

to

JAVA_CMD="$JENKINS_JAVA_CMD -Dhudson.model.DownloadService.noSignatureCheck=true $JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS -DJENKINS_HOME=$JENKINS_HOME -jar $JENKINS_WAR"

After this change, the installation getting started but again the plugins are failed to install.

[image]

can someone please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Hello. Which is the error?

Comment: The issue is I'm not able to install the plugins in jenkins.